# Luxonjs and mongoose

Tags: date, mongoose, luxon

I'm trying to migrate from momentjs to luxonjs and I'm facing an issue regarding the date format sent by mongoose.

In mongoose docs, date format is a RFC822.
Exemple : Fri Jun 25 2021 08:36:03 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)

When using moment, just doing a `moment(mongooseDate)` works perfectly.

I tried many different functions on luxon without success, hHow to make luxon work with mongoose datetime result.

Thanks

Code Exemple

```
//date is the result of the query on a date field
  console.log('MOONGOOSE DATE :', date)
  const momentValue = moment(date)
  console.log('MOMENT : ', momentValue)
  const luxonValue = DateTime.fromRFC2822(date)
  console.log('LUXON : ', luxonValue.toObject())
```

[Code Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKYuC.png)

[Console Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO1A9.png)

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem with luxon, so you need to try converting  `.fromISO`, instead of `.fromRFC2822`

```
  console.log('MOONGOOSE DATE :', date)
  const momentValue = moment(date)
  console.log('MOMENT : ', momentValue)
  const luxonValue = DateTime.fromISO(date)
  console.log('LUXON : ', luxonValue.toObject())
```

Comment: please embed the code directly in the answer, without using the screenshot